# Em dash using |

Tags: punctuation

I accidentally, discovered that using `|` in text mode produces an em dash. I did a quick search, but I could not find a reference where this is noted. I wonder if there is any difference between this and `---`? Otherwise, it seems easier to just type one character instead of three.

Comment: It's a quirk of the OT1 font encoding. You can lose it if you change the font encoding. There are probably many questions about it on this site…

Comment: I asked about that in chat once. 
 [barbara answered](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26780330#26780330).

Comment: iirc in `ltxdoc` class which is usually used in `dtx` files, the `|` is automatically a `\verb` delimiter, i.e.`|\foo|` renders `\foo` verbatim.

Comment: ... and with T1 encoding (` \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is just `|` : Moral: just use `--- `to be sure that em dash will be always an em dash.

Comment: Or systematically use T1 font encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as a result of the default font encoding `OT1`. It places an — (em-dash) in the spot associated with |. To highlight this, consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\showoutput

|

---

\end{document}
```

`\showoutput` adds content to the `.log` that shows the construction of the output pages. The following excerpt was taken from the above example's `.log`:

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(633.0+0.0)x407.0
.\glue 16.0
.\vbox(617.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 62.0
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 527.9436fil
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 5.69446
...\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x345.0, glue set 319.99998fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 |
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.69446
...\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x345.0, glue set 319.99998fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 | (ligature ---)
....\discretionary
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 23.55556
..\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 170.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

There are 3 instances where the font was used:

- `....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 |` = `|`
- `....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 | (ligature ---)` = `---`
- `...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1` = page number

Note how the ligature `---` uses the same font character `|`. Now add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to the preamble and you'll get

- `....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 |` = `|`
- `....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 ^^V (ligature ---)` = `---`
- `...\T1/cmr/m/n/10 1` = page number

Different characters are grabbed for `|` and `---` from the font table under the `T1` font encoding, resulting in a different display.

---

I'd stick to a syntax that provides some intuitive semantics when viewing your code. That is, if you want an em-dash, use `---` (or `—` under `\usepackage{inputenc}`) rather than `|`.

Analogously, it's better to use something in your code that would resemble what you'd expect in the output. As an example, use `\circle` to define a circle as output rather than it outputting a square or line, say.

Comment: the monotype fonts are an exception: in OT1 encoding they do typically produce a `|` glyph from `|` input.